# Use backgroundworker in VC++ 2010

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, backgroundworker

I want to make a program that zip by backup files, but the program hangs when zipping files. I tried to use backgroundworker to execute the work.

this is my code so far:

```
private: System::Void threadTest_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         debug->Text = L"Zipping...";
         zip->RunWorkerAsync();
         if(zip->IsBusy)
         {
            bkProgress->Increment(20);
            Application::DoEvents();
         }
         //zip->OnDoWork();
     }
```

This is `DoWork` code for my backgroundworker:

```
private: System::Void zip_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
            //zipping file code here
            refreshAll();
     }
```

I found out that `refreshAll()`won't run and I can't tell when the thread is stopped, I think I did something wrong here, can you give me some tips, I am really new to CLR. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if RefreshAll make changes to GUI, you have to take care to the following rule:

Never change the GUI from another thread than the main thread where the Gui was created.

In you case you have to use Form::Invoke method to switch to the main thread like that

```
this->Invoke(gcnew RefreshAllDelegate(), new Object[] { message });
```

And of course you have to create a delegate RefreshAllDelegate.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not explaining this question right. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the code after RunWorkerAsync(), it will only make your app crash when the user closes the form while zipping is in progress.  In the DoWork() method, use the bgw's ReportProgress() method to report progress.  You can write an event handler for the event to update the UI.  Move refreshAll() into the bgw's RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Do review the examples giving the MSDN Library article for BackgroundWorker.  BGW was designed to make multi-threading with the UI easy but if you are using it wrong then you'll just buy a lot of grief.  Practice the examples first before making it work in your own code.